# Paste-Collapse numbers in R

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I have three variables:

```
s num [1:4] 8 1 8 6
q num [1:4] 1 2 3 3
c num [1:4] 3 3 3 3
```

I want to concatenate and collapse the variables, so I do this:

```
num <- (paste(s,q,c,sep = "", collapse=" "))
```

And the result is that I want:

```
num [1] "813 123 833 633"
```

But my problem now is that the result is no longer numeric and I want them separated and numeric, how could I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `as.numeric(strsplit(num, " ")[[1]])`??

Comment: David perfect, I know that it would be easy, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
as.numeric(paste(s,q,c,sep=""))
```

?

Comment: or `as.numeric(paste0(s,q,c))`

Comment: Didn't work for me Karsten, thank you anyway, David's answer was perfect.